# What does a 5.5 VDC rating on a super capacitor imply?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, supercapacitor, ratings

I'm confused as to what a 5.5 VDC rating on super capacitor implies.  Is this with respect to 5.5 VDC tolerance, impedance, or feedthrough?

You can find the product details at:
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/80-FC0H105ZFTBR44-SS

Thanks.

Comment: It means useful for 5V with+ 10% absolute max

Comment: Why do you think tolerance, feed through, or impedance (especially the second two) have anything to do with the 5.5VDC as listed?

Comment: I was wondering if the rating was with regard to max current transfer/throughput, I guess impedance doesn't make sense with conventional use.

Comment: @jv1597 That would be your ripple current rating (or something similar).

Comment: Yes ripple current rating does make more sense for use for determining rate of discharge/noise rectification of a capacitor.  With regard to Tony's post: How would it be possible to store, or to attempt to store more than the rated VDC on a capacitor?  Just trying to make sense of the rating, and what it's good for..:)

Comment: So 5.5 VDC would mean tolerance up to 5.5V on a circuit...which accrues damage with anything over 5.5V?  Correct?

Comment: @jv1597 Never let the cap charge up to anything past 5.5V at any time during the circuit's operation.

Comment: To achieve a higher voltage you could wire two or more similar parts in series, (of course you would then reduce the available capacitance).  Alternately you could attach a step-up voltage circuit following a single super capacitor.

Comment: Spec sheet [here](https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/212/KEM_S6011_FC-1104096.pdf) says Maximum Operating Voltage - they also have a surge voltage (6.3V) - READ the SPEC sheet. Note what it says.

Answer (score 1):

It's with respect to the capacitor failing, possibly in a dramatic and smoky manner.

Basically, a supercap, like a normal capacitor, will fail in some manner when you try to store too much energy in it (by trying to put too high a voltage on it).  Exactly how depends on the construction.

Check the [Wikipedia article on supercaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor#Operating_voltage) for details on the failure mechanism, or go web-searching.

Answer (score 1):

It means the capacitor will **not** be damaged by voltages from 0V to 5.5V (of the correct polarity).

No guarantees about what happens at 6V or 5.5001V for that matter. At some voltage it will be destroyed.

The data sheet says: “There is no harm (normal failure mode of liquid leakage) as it is a mere leak of water vapor which transitioned from water contained in the electrolyte (diluted sulfuric acid). However, application of abnormal voltage surge exceeding maximum operating voltage may result in leakage and explosion”.

Comment: Ok, I think that clears it up well enough.  Along those lines, exactly how does 10V supply voltage on a 5.5VDC rated capacitor damage the capacitor without a load applied on the capacitor itself?  Does the capacitor take as much as it is supplied with or does it only take up to the max VDC rating?

Comment: Probably breakdown of an extremely thin layer of dielectric, followed by excessive current, production of steam, venting or explosion.